# Understand use of require in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the use of the keyword 'require' in perl. I have referred  [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) but it is not very helpful.

From http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html

> require Demands a version of Perl specified by VERSION, or demands
>   some semantics specified by EXPR or by $_ if EXPR is not supplied.
>   VERSION may be either a numeric argument such as 5.006, which will be
>   compared to $] , or a literal of the form v5.6.1, which will be
>   compared to $^V (aka $PERL_VERSION). An exception is raised if VERSION
>   is greater than the version of the current Perl interpreter. Compare
>   with use, which can do a similar check at compile time.

From this it is not quite clear what the below line of code implies in a PERL script on a Linux machine with a higher version of PERL install(say 5.22):-

```
require 5.006_001;
```

Could it be explained with an example, in what scenarios might one need to use it?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe start by telling us what you want to do? It sounds like you might try to translate Perl code to some other language. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: `require` - it's something without what your program should/will not work, you may specify perl version, or some files. Actually your link is very helpful, and please answer on @simbabque question. What you want to do?

Comment: `require` is very little use. One normally loads a module using `use` instead, which is a compile-time version of `require`.

Comment: I'd chat with @alekh-chaudhary, wherein he wanted to understand the use of 'require <perl-version>'

Comment: @simbabque is the question clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you have linked and quotes explains this on the very first page, without scrolling. (Emphasis mine).

> **VERSION may be either a numeric argument such as 5.006, which will be
>   compared to `$]`** , or a literal of the form v5.6.1, which will be
>   compared to $^V (aka $PERL_VERSION). **An exception is raised if VERSION
>   is greater than the version of the current Perl interpreter.** Compare
>   with use, which can do a similar check at compile time.

One paragraph down is this example.

> ```
> require v5.6.1;     # run time version check
> require 5.6.1;      # ditto
> require 5.006_001;  # ditto; preferred for backwards
>                       compatibility
> ```

So it's pretty clear what it does. It *requires* your Perl to be at least  5.6.1 at run time. If you have 5.22, all is well.

### Examples on CPAN

Finding cases where this feature is used is pretty simple with [grep.cpan.me](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=require%205.012), but actually getting some with a decent explanation required a bit of searching<sup>1</sup>.

- [Astro::App::Satpass2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Astro::App::Satpass2) is using `require 5.012` and `require 5.010` [in its lib module My::Module::Recommend](https://metacpan.org/source/WYANT/Astro-App-Satpass2-0.030/inc/My/Module/Recommend.pm#L12). Apparently there are some big number features it needs [that don't work on older Perls](https://metacpan.org/source/WYANT/Astro-App-Satpass2-0.030/inc/My/Module/Recommend.pm#L167).
- [Barcode::Code128](http://p3rl.org/Barcode::Code128) has [`require 5.010`](https://metacpan.org/source/WRW/Barcode-Code128-2.21/lib/Barcode/Code128.pm#L1), but its [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Barcode::Code128#REQUIRES) says it needs Perl 5.004.
- [Mail::SpamAssassin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::SpamAssassin) says [in its changelog](https://metacpan.org/source/KMCGRAIL/Mail-SpamAssassin-3.4.1/Changes#L415) that a `require 5.008001` was added to fix a bug with a missing `utf8::is_utf8()`.

The last one is a good example of the different number styles. Not only does it need a specific sub-version of 5.08, it also leaves out the `_`, which can be used anywhere in numbers to make them more readable in Perl.

A more hands-on example, but harder to find on CPAN, would be if you absolutely need to use a specific syntax feature that only became available in a very recent Perl, like the `/r` flag on the substitution operator `s///`, that adds non-destructive substitution, so the result is returned instead of the string manipulated. [It was added in Perl 5.014](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perldelta.html#Non-destructive-substitution). If your code depends on that, you would put `require 5.014` at the top so it doesn't even try to run on older Perls as it would fail anyway.

```
return $foo->frobnicate(
  id => $params->{id},
  text_without_whitespace => $params->{text} =~ s/\s+//gr,
);
```

---

<sup>1) Reading the CPAN is useful. Do it.</sup>

Comment: Could it be explained with an example, in what scenarios might one need to use it?

Comment: @Phalgun I added a few examples from CPAN

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!